# condition on openlayers.vector using json

Tags: javascript, json, vector, openlayers, geojson

I'd like to retrieve some informations from json using openlayers.vector but in condition :
for example (if "type"="etat5") retrieve url and name

```
    var geojson_etat7 = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("etat7", {
        styleMap: new OpenLayers.StyleMap({
                    "default": new OpenLayers.Style({
                    externalGraphic: './images/Etat${url}.png', 
                    graphicWidth: 21, 
                    graphicHeight: 25,
                    graphicYOffset: -24,
    ===>>>>>>               label : "name: ${name}"

                    } ),

                }),
        projection: epsg4326,
        strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed()],
        protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({
            url: "data/data_etat5.geojson",
            format: new OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON()
            })

        });
```

This is my db json :

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"features": [
{
  "type": "etat5",
  "properties": {
        "name": "test",
        "amenity": "toto",
        "popupContent": "popo",
        "url":"5"
    },
  "geometry": {
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [
      26.9140625,
      26.9449741808516
    ]
  }
},
{
  "type": "etat5",
  "properties": {
          "name": "tt",
          "url":"5"
  },
  "geometry": {
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [
     53.15008544921875,
      21.3425828520359735
    ]
  }
},
{
  "type": "etat1",
  "properties": {
        "name": "test",
        "amenity": "toto",
        "popupContent": "popo",
        "url":"1"

    },
  "geometry": {
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [
      38.9140625,
      56.9449741808516
    ]
  }
},
   {
  "type": "etat1",
  "properties": {"url":"1"},
  "geometry": {
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [
      -2.15008544921875,
      1.3425828520359735
    ]
  }
},
{
  "type": "etat2",
  "properties": {
        "name": "test",
        "amenity": "toto",
        "popupContent": "popo",
        "url":"2"

    },
  "geometry": {
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [
      26.9140625,
      46.9449741808516
    ]
  }
},
   {
  "type": "etat2",
  "properties": {"url":"2"},
  "geometry": {
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [
     3.15008544921875,
      11.3425828520359735
    ]
  }
},
{
  "type": "etat3",
  "properties": {
        "name": "test",
        "amenity": "toto",
        "popupContent": "popo",
        "url":"3"
    },
  "geometry": {
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [
      16.9140625,
      26.9449741808516
    ]
  }
},
   {
  "type": "etat3",
  "properties": {"url":"3"},
  "geometry": {
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [
     23.15008544921875,
      31.3425828520359735
    ]
  }
},
  {
  "type": "etat4",
  "properties": {
        "name": "test",
        "amenity": "toto",
        "popupContent": "popo",
        "url":"4"
    },
  "geometry": {
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [
      3.9140625,
      16.9449741808516
    ]
  }
},
   {
  "type": "etat4",
  "properties": {"url":"4"},
  "geometry": {
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [
     23.15008544921875,
      71.3425828520359735
    ]
  }
},
{
  "type": "etat6",
  "properties": {
        "name": "test",
        "amenity": "toto",
        "popupContent": "popo",
        "url":"6"
    },
  "geometry": {
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [
      16.9140625,
      36.9449741808516
    ]
  }
},
   {
  "type": "etat6",
  "properties": {"url":"6"},
  "geometry": {
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [
     43.15008544921875,
      111.3425828520359735
    ]
    }
   }
 ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this, because type is used by the GeoJSON parser to determine the feature type between Geometry, Feature and FeatureCollection, see the comments of the [read method](http://trac.osgeo.org/openlayers/browser/trunk/openlayers/lib/OpenLayers/Format/GeoJSON.js).

However, the properties are parsed, and these become part of the attributes of the Feature Vectors that are returned from the GeoJSON.read function. If you put the type within your properties (assuming you can change the structure), then it will get picked up and added as an attribute of the feature, which you could then access like this:

```
var reader=new OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON();
var features=reader.read(json);
for (var i=0; i<features.length; i++){
    if(features[i].attributes['type']==='etat5'){
         console.log(features[i].attributes['url']);
    }
};
```

and an example of how your JSON would work with this.

```
var json={
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [{  
     "properties": {
        "type": "etat5",
        "name": "test",
        "amenity": "toto",
        "popupContent": "popo",
        "url":"5"
    },
     "geometry": {
       "type": "Point",
       "coordinates": [
       26.9140625,
       26.9449741808516
     ]
    } 
  }
]};
```

Comment: but with this methode i can't use an external file json ?!!

Comment: i found this method but i have the same problem :

Comment: You can, you just need to change the structure so that type: etat5 is inside the properties, not outside.

Answer (score 0):

var geojson_etat7 = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("etat7", {
            styleMap: new OpenLayers.StyleMap({

```
                    "default": new OpenLayers.Style({
                    externalGraphic: './images/Etat${nom}.png', 
                    graphicWidth: 21, 
                    graphicHeight: 25,
                    graphicYOffset: -24,
                    label : "${tot}"
                    },
                    { context: {
                        tot: function(feature){
                            var tt=" etat7";
                            //return tt;
                            if(feature.attributes.url=="4"){
                            return  tt;
                            }


                        },
                        nom: function(feature){
                            var tt="4";
                            //return tt;
                            if(feature.attributes.url=="4"){
                            return  tt;
                            }


                        }
                    }
                    } )  

                }),
        projection: epsg4326,
        strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed()],
        protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({
            url: "data/data_etat5.geojson",
            format: new OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON()
            })

        });
```